# firebase cloud functions: thumbnail creation with sharp library is not generating access token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am generating thumbnail images with `sharp` library as follows:

```
    const filePath128       =   path.join(path.dirname(filePath), `${_128_PREFIX}${fileName}`);
    const filePath512       =   path.join(path.dirname(filePath), `${_512_PREFIX}${fileName}`);
    const filePath1024      =   path.join(path.dirname(filePath), `${fileName}`);

    const uploadStream128   =   bucket.file(filePath128).createWriteStream({metadata});
    const uploadStream512   =   bucket.file(filePath512).createWriteStream({metadata});
    const uploadStream1024  =   bucket.file(filePath1024).createWriteStream({metadata});

    const pipeline128       =   sharp();
    pipeline128.resize(_128_MAX_WIDTH, _128_MAX_HEIGHT).pipe(uploadStream128);
    const pipeline512       =   sharp();
    pipeline512.resize(_512_MAX_WIDTH, _512_MAX_HEIGHT).pipe(uploadStream512);
    const pipeline1024      =   sharp();
    pipeline1024.resize(_1024_MAX_WIDTH, _1024_MAX_HEIGHT).pipe(uploadStream1024);

    bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline128);
    bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline512);
    bucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline1024);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let finishCount     =   0;

        const checkFinish = (ee: any) => {
            finishCount++;
            console.log('finishCount: ', finishCount, ee);
            if (finishCount === 3) { resolve(); }
        }

        uploadStream128.on('finish', checkFinish).on('error', checkFinish);
        uploadStream512.on('finish', checkFinish).on('error', checkFinish);
        uploadStream1024.on('finish', checkFinish).on('error', checkFinish);
    });
```

All the thumbnail images are getting generated without any problem. But access token was not created for them by default. In Firebase console, I can't even view the generated image files. Once after I do `Create new access token` link from the console, the image becomes viewable.

Any help on how to tackle this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently can't be solved from Cloud Functions.  You can [create a download URL programmatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) from a Firebase client app (which will create the token), but not from backend code.